# Get the value form a another input field

Tags: jquery

This is the input field on fourth place:

```
<td><input type="number" name="tour" value="12" size="2" maxlength="2"></td>
```

This Js dosnt work:

```
var hTour = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(4)').val();
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Well, what is `this` referring to?

Comment: `td` tags don't  have a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually with your code:

```
var hTour = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(4)').val();
```

you are looking for the value inside the `td`. But you need the value of input inside the `td` like:

```
var hTour = $(this).parent('tr').find('td:nth-child(4) input').val();
```

From the [**:nth-child() Selector API docs**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

> **index**: The index of each child to match, starting with 1, the string
>   even or odd, or an equation ( eg. :nth-child(even), :nth-child(4n) )

Also

```
Given a single <ul> containing two <li>s, $('li:nth-child(1)') selects
the first <li> while $('li:eq(1)') selects the second.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript is getting the value of a `td` element. You probably want the `input` element's value:

```
var hTour = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3) input').val();
```

`:nth-child()` is zero-indexed, so `:nth-child(0)` is the first element, `:nth-child(1)` is the second, and so on.